# CSS background with 2 colors which expand themselves to their sides?

Tags: css, background

The following page has white (left) and dark gray (right) background. I checked the CSS and it has a white background image and `color: #FFF`. I can't figure out how did he archived that.

How to do that?

http://www.voceantica.com/

(If you enlarge the web browser both colors enlarge themselves too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has a huge backgroundimage on the html tag:

```
html {
  background: url("images/bg.gif") repeat scroll center top #FFFFFF;
}
```

Check the image:

http://www.voceantica.com/wp-content/themes/tao/images/bg.gif

Answer (score 1):

It's done with a really long [BG image](http://www.voceantica.com/wp-content/themes/tao/images/bg.gif). Set that as the html background and position your divs accordingly :)

```
html {
background:#FFFFFF url(images/bg.gif) repeat scroll center top;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background gif is 3000px wide. Half white, half dark grey.

Answer (score 0):

It will work perfectly fine at any resolution.

```
body{
    background:url("img/home_page_bg.gif") repeat scroll center top #fff;
    }
```